# Wait for default animation of MenuItem adding to finish

Tags: c#, uwp

I am currently creating a NavigationViewItem and add it to an existing NavigationView. After that i want to navigate to it.

```
 NavigationViewItem item = new NavigationViewItem() {/*...*/};
 NavView.MenuItems.Add(item);
 ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Project), item);
 var menuItem = NavView.MenuItems
                .OfType<NavigationViewItem>()
                .Where(item => item.Tag.ToString() == tag)
                .First();
 NavView.SelectedItem = menuItem;
```

But after i add it to the list and select the menu item, it still does the "adding"-animation, so it doesn't trigger the "active menu-item" animation or rather the (blue) indicator on the left side:

[image: NavigationView with active indicator]

So in the end, the indicator is missing. Clicking on the menu item again also doesn't make it appear, only after navigating away from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested your code and it indeed makes that "worm-like" animation for the item "pipe" as it adds the item to the menu.

Here's a simple approach but don't know if this is a good code but somehow worked for me.

```
  await Task.Delay(500);
```

Added the code after adding the item and before selecting that item.

EDIT:

```
NavigationViewItem item = new NavigationViewItem()  { ... };
nvMain.MenuItems.Add(item);
await Task.Delay(500);
SelectAddedItem(item);    //Method to select the item
```